# Is there a block visibility condition for entity types?

Tags: blocks, 10

By default, Drupal core's node module provides a "Content type" visibility condition for node content types.

Is there a similar "Entity type" visibility condition to restrict block visibility by entities?

It seems like an obvious use case, so I tried searching but haven't been able to find anything-- it seems there's no such thing in core itself, or in Ctools, or in the Block Visibility Conditions contrib module.

Comment: It is, first it was in Ctools and then moved to core. However, the entity type needs to have bundles to be recognized by this plugin. The visibility condition in the node module is deprecated by the way.

Comment: About the use case, I think most people would use the canonical entity path, for example `/user/*`, if they don't need to filter a specific bundle.